# Is it possible to use the Android SDK without using eclipse?

Tags: android, linux, gedit

I'd like to develop for Android but I don't really like using an IDE for programming as I find them to be pretty cumbersome compared to a text editor and command console. Is there any way I can develop for Android without doing so in Eclipse, and instead using Gedit? The system requirements specified on the Android developers site list Eclipse as a requirement, but I Ewas wondering if anyone had found a way to manually tap into the SDK libraries outside of Eclipse. I'm using a Linux setup as my development box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not have to use Eclipse, it's just highly recommended because the tools are nicely integrated :

> The recommended way to develop an
>   Android application is to use Eclipse
>   with the ADT plugin. The ADT plugin
>   provides editing, building, debugging,
>   and .apk packaging and signing
>   functionality integrated right into
>   the IDE.
>
> However, if you'd rather develop your
>   application in another IDE, such as
>   IntelliJ, or in a basic editor, such
>   as Emacs, you can do that instead. The
>   SDK includes all the tools you need to
>   set up an Android project, build it,
>   debug it and then package it for
>   distribution. This document is your
>   guide to using these tools.

See this page on the Dev Guide for more info: [Developing In Other IDEs](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/other-ide.html)

Answer (score 3):

Yes you *can* do it with just the SDK and Ant (and the JDK of course). I'm doing it right now as an exercise in relearning Ant, and to make an 'idiot push button' procedure for a release build.

I've got to say that it's slow going just trying to configure the build process on sources that I know will compile. I'm glad that I've got Eclipse for the rapid development in the  debug phase.